# Pass a delegate to a generic function and then Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer()

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, delegates, unmanaged

I would like to write a generic and reusable function to facilitate the common task of calling an export function in a native dll and return the function's return value.

Consider my following approach:

```
Shared Function CallNativeFunction(Of TResult)(
                                   ByVal filepath As String,
                                   ByVal functionName As String,
                                   ByVal functionSignature As [Delegate]) As TResult

    Dim hLib As IntPtr = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(filepath)
    If (hLib = IntPtr.Zero) Then
        Throw New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
    End If

    Dim dllEntryPoint As IntPtr = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(hLib, functionName)
    If (dllEntryPoint = IntPtr.Zero) Then
        Throw New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
    End If

    functionSignature = 
        Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(dllEntryPoint, GetType([Delegate]))

    Dim result As TResult = 
        Conversion.CTypeDynamic(Of TResult)(functionSignature)

    Return result

End Function
```

Or also with this alternative signature:

```
Shared Function CallNativeFunction(Of TResult, TDelegate)(
                                   ByVal filepath As String,
                                   ByVal functionName As String,
                                   ByVal functionSignature As TDelegate) As TResult

...
```

Well, I'm breaking my head trying to figue which would be the best approach at the moment to define the Type parameters of the function, and how could I pass the right arguments to the function to let it work as expected. 
Now it doesn't work as expected; when I pass a `[Delegate]` the the function, the call to `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` throws an `ArgumentException` saying that the argument must derive from `[Delegate]` type, and if I pass a `Func(of T)`, it says the type must not be a generic type.

So, imagine that for example I would like to call a "**DllRegisterServer**" exported in native dll, to accmplish that task I should write this code below:

```
<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Friend Delegate Function PointerToMethodInvoker() As Integer

Sub CallNativeFunction(...)
    ' non-relevant code here ...
    ' ...
    Dim invoker As PointerToMethodInvoker = 
        Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(Of PointerToMethodInvoker)(dllEntryPoint)

    Dim result As Integer = invoker()
End Sub
```

...But that code is hardcoded, the delegate is defined at class level and inside the block of `CallNativeFunction` I must know the exact name of the delegate defined to proceed. I want to avoid/simplify those things. My purpose is to transform that code example, into a reusable function to be able pass a non-hardcoded `[Delegate]`.

My Question: how can I adapt my current code to satisfy the expected behavior that I explained?.

Comment: Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(dllEntryPoint, functionSignature.GetType())

Comment: @Hans Passant Thankyou for providing that tip, but maybe I ask too much if could you also provide an example of how it needs to be declared (inside of a method block) a working/acceptable object that derives from [Delegate] to be able pass it to my function?

Comment: I'll share a piece of code that I wrote minutes ago to show one declaration that works, and one that doesn't works: https://pastebin.com/CGv0jDh4 the problem is that I need to avoid the declaration of the delegate at class level, so i'm trying to figure how can make it work the code that doesn't works. The code that does not work throws an exception when calling **GetDelegateForFunctionPointer** saying this: 'The specified Type must not be a generic type definition'...

Comment: A very basic flaw in this method is that it cannot pass any arguments to the native function.  It is missing a Params Object() argument, what you can pass to Delegate.DynamicInvoke().  So the delegate type can only ever be Func(Of TResult).  And no, you must nail down what TResult is, so only Func(Of Integer) can work.  And no, a delegate type cannot be a generic type argument.  Making it too universal is not very useful, there is no meaningful type checking and getting it wrong always produces an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a temporal solution. This is not as universal as I would like it to be, but something is always better than nothing and i think a considerable portion of code will be saved when using this function without losing too much movility/efficiency and error-handling. One thing I'm not sure is how could I handle the disambiguation when there are two exports defined with same name but different signatures.

**IF SOMEONE HAS A BETTER APPROACH THAN MINE, THEN PLEASE PUBLISH AN ANSWER. IM NOT GOING TO ACCEPT MY OWN ANSWER.** Thanks for the help, tips and/or suggestions that were bringed to me in the comments boxes of my question.

I wrote two functions, one for getting the native function passing a delegate (so the end-user could do whatever he wants to do with the returned delegate), and the other for execute the function, its kinda written with the concept in mind: "*do this task easy with none difficulties for me*", is not too much safe, I know, but well... its just a simple helper method.

I wish this code could be useful for someone in some specific scenarios. Usage examples are wrote inside the XML documentation. The code lacks of some required Windows API definitions to avoid making a too much bigger code, I think its enough as is, everyone can look for the required definitions on [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net).

---

### GetNativeFunction

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Gets a function exported in a native dll.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code>
''' Public Module Module1
''' 
'''     ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'''     ''' &lt;summary&gt;
'''     ''' A delegate to call DllRegisterServer or DllUnregisterServer functions in a native dll.
'''     ''' &lt;/summary&gt;
'''     ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'''     ''' &lt;returns&gt;
'''     ''' The result of calling DllRegisterServer or DllUnregisterServer functions in a native dll.
'''     ''' &lt;/returns&gt;
'''     ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'''     &lt;UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)&gt;
'''     Friend Delegate Function PointerToRegistrationMethodInvoker() As Integer
''' 
'''     Public Sub Main()
''' 
'''         Dim methodInvoker As PointerToRegistrationMethodInvoker =
'''                 GetNativeFunction(Of PointerToRegistrationMethodInvoker)("C:\native.dll", "DllRegisterServer")
''' 
'''         Dim result As Integer = methodInvoker.Invoke()
'''         If (result &lt;&gt; 0) Then
'''             ' ToDo: Handle specific errors...
'''         End If
''' 
'''     End Sub
''' 
''' End Module
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <typeparam name="TDelegate">
''' The <see cref="Type"/> of the source <see cref="[Delegate]"/> 
''' that will represent the signature of the native function.
''' </typeparam>
'''  
''' <param name="filepath">
''' The file path of the native dll.
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="functionName">
''' The name of the function to be retrieved.
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <returns>
''' The resulting <see cref="[Delegate]"/> which represents a pointer to the method invoker.
''' </returns>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Shared Function GetNativeFunction(Of TDelegate)(ByVal filepath As String,
                                                       ByVal functionName As String) As TDelegate

    Dim hLib As IntPtr
    Dim win32err As Integer

    hLib = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(filepath)
    win32err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
    If (hLib = IntPtr.Zero) Then
        If (win32err = Win32ErrorCode.ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT) Then ' 193
            Throw New BadImageFormatException("Failed to load library.", filepath)
        ElseIf (win32err = Win32ErrorCode.ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND) Then ' 126
            Throw New FileNotFoundException("File not found.", filepath)
        Else
            Throw New Win32Exception(win32err)
        End If
    End If

    Dim dllEntryPoint As IntPtr = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(hLib, functionName)
    win32err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
    If (dllEntryPoint = IntPtr.Zero) Then
        If (win32err = Win32ErrorCode.ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND) Then ' 127
            Throw New EntryPointNotFoundException(String.Format("Failed to get entry point: '{0}'", functionName))
        Else
            Throw New Win32Exception(win32err)
        End If
    End If

    Return Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(Of TDelegate)(dllEntryPoint)

End Function
```

---

### CallNativeFunction

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Executes a function exported in a native dll and returns the result value.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code>
''' Public Module Module1
''' 
'''     ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'''     ''' &lt;summary&gt;
'''     ''' A delegate to call DllRegisterServer or DllUnregisterServer functions in a native dll.
'''     ''' &lt;/summary&gt;
'''     ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'''     ''' &lt;returns&gt;
'''     ''' The result of calling DllRegisterServer or DllUnregisterServer functions in a native dll.
'''     ''' &lt;/returns&gt;
'''     ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'''     &lt;UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)&gt;
'''     Friend Delegate Function PointerToRegistrationMethodInvoker() As Integer
''' 
'''     Public Sub Main()
''' 
'''         Dim result As Integer = 
'''             CallNativeFunction(Of Integer, PointerToRegistrationMethodInvoker)(filepath, "DllRegisterServer", Nothing)
''' 
'''         Dim result As Integer = methodInvoker.Invoke()
'''         If (result &lt;&gt; 0) Then
'''             ' ToDo?: Handle specific errors...
'''         End If
''' 
'''     End Sub
''' 
''' End Module
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <typeparam name="TResult">
''' The <see cref="Type"/> of the value returned by the native function.
''' </typeparam>
'''  
''' <typeparam name="TDelegate">
''' The <see cref="Type"/> of the source <see cref="[Delegate]"/> 
''' that will represent the signature of the native function.
''' </typeparam>
'''
''' <param name="filepath">
''' The file path of the native dll.
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="functionName">
''' The name of the function to be executed.
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="functionSignature">
''' A <see cref="[Delegate]"/> that will represent the signature of the native function.
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="parameters">
''' An argument list for the invoked function. 
''' This is an array of objects with the same number, order, and type as the parameters of the function to be invoked.
''' <para></para>
''' If there are no parameters, parameters should be null.If the method
''' Any object in this array that is not explicitly initialized with a value will contain the default value for
''' that object type. 
''' <para></para>
''' For reference-type elements, this value is <see langword="Nothing"/>. 
''' For value-type elements, this value is 0, 0.0, or false, depending on the specific element type.
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <returns>
''' The result of calling the native function.
''' </returns>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Shared Function CallNativeFunction(Of TResult, TDelegate)(ByVal filepath As String,
                                                                 ByVal functionName As String,
                                                                 ByVal functionSignature As TDelegate,
                                                                 ByVal ParamArray parameters As Object()) As TResult

    functionSignature = GetNativeFunction(Of TDelegate)(filepath, functionName)

    Dim methodInvoker As MulticastDelegate = Conversion.CTypeDynamic(Of MulticastDelegate)(functionSignature)
    Dim result As TResult = CType(methodInvoker.DynamicInvoke(parameters), TResult)
    Return result

End Function
```